# Solve $\iint_A xy^3e^{x^2-y^4} \,dx\,dy$ where $A$ is the domain bounded between $x=4,\;y=0,\;x^2-y^4=9,$ and $x^2-y^4=1$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Solve $\iint_A xy^3e^{x^2-y^4} \,dx\,dy$ where $A$ is the domain bounded between $x=4,\;y=0,\;x^2-y^4=9,$ and $x^2-y^4=1$.
>
> Hint: Use the substitution $x^2-y^4=v,\;x^2=u.$

I have some difficulties with this problem.

I was already given the substitution, but what I struggle with here is understanding how $u$ and $v$ are bounded, and if they form a simple domain.

Showing this transformation is injective is simple, and calculating the Jacobian and later, the integral itself it not problematic, but I can't understand how to reach the bounds of the integral.

Most importantly:

How are those bounds calculated? I have seen some examples but they were very basic, so I am quite clueless now.

How can I be sure that I reach the right bounds for $u$ and $v$ and simply not making stuff up? It seems totally random to me at this point, with zero ways to review my work before checking the solution. I thought I reached the correct bounds, but I saw I had a mistake.

I know those are very general questions, perhaps an explanation for the answer for this specific question will help (plus explaining why are you sure your answer is correct).

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: First question: did you draw a sketch of the region $A$?  In this case it's not altogether easy, but you should be able to get something.

Comment: I have something but I wouldn't count on it.  I would rather see a solution that doesn't rely on a sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits for $v$ are already given by 1 and 9. The limits for $u$ can be translated as follows:

$$x=4 \stackrel{u=x^2}\mapsto u=16,\quad y=0 \stackrel{v=x^2-y^4}\mapsto u=v.$$

Thus the integration domain in the coordinates $(u,v)$ Is a trapezoid with boundary consisting of four line segments connecting the points $(1,1)-(9,9)-(16,9)-(16,1)-(1,1)$.

Comment: How do you know that you should take into consideration only $x=4$ and $y=0$? Also, can you elaborate how you reached those limits for $u$, and how are you sure that you don't miss something?

Comment: We have only 4 equations for the domain bound, and two of them ($x^2-y^4=9,$ and $x^2-y^4=1$) are already used. There remain only $x=4$ and $y=0$ which we shall express in terms of $u$ and $v$, and since, as you correctly state, the map $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v)$ is injective, the expression is unique.

Comment: Each equation is only used once? Is that always the case?

Comment: Normal transformations without singularities in the considered domain (as in your case) map each piece of the boundary described by an equation onto a piece of a boundary described by the image of this equation.

Comment: Really? I had no idea! So if I find use for one boundary I don't need to consider it for the next ones?

Comment: I am really happy that the information  was helpful to you.